# Consistent way to use "cursor: pointer" in HTML email?

Tags: html, outlook, mailing-list

I'm styling an HTML Email notification for our process automation software.  Everything is going grand, except I can't get "Cursor: pointer" to work on the buttons.  Works great in IE9, Chrome, of course, just not in my Outlook 2010 client.  Any solutions should also be compatible with Outlook 2007 if possible.

I did try "Cursor: hand" with no luck just for fun.

Comment: Outlook 2010 is not very good with HTML and CSS. Sorry, but that´s the way it is. Would it help if I suggested another email client, or webmail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can simply use an `<a>` tag instead and style it appropriately with CSS?

Comment: I think that is a very good start. <a href="#">something</a> because I think that omitting the href attribute causes the cursor to change back to a selector in some cases

Comment: Yeah, immediately after posting my question I did that and it worked.  Since I was simply trying to create a template I neglected to put in any actual links.  It does work with an anchor tag though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that Outlook doesn't allow that CSS rule. Most mail clients restrict the HTML/CSS that will be parsed in messages, and exactly what is restricted varies by client. As an example, I remember that at least older versions of Outlook/OE wouldn't render forms in an email, while Thunderbird would.

Check here:
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2533/a-guide-to-css-support-in-emai-2/

Doesn't have Outlook 2010, but it definitely states that 2007 doesn't support the CSS `cursor`.